# Moment generating function of a random number of IIDs?

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Let's imagine I've got $Q_1,\ldots,Q_L$ independent identically distributed normal random variables with parameters $\mu, \sigma^2$, and $L$ is binomial with parameters $n,p$.

Let $Y=Q_1+\cdots+Q_L$.

Then $M_Y(s)$ is a random variable satisfying $$M_Y(s \mid L=l) = e^{l\left( \mu s + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 s^2 \right)}.$$

Is the moment generating function for $Y$ equal to:

$$\begin{align}
M_Y(s) &= \sum_k {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}M_Q(s)^k\\
&= \sum_k {n \choose k} \left( p M_Q(s) \right)^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
&= \cdots\text{ ?}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, the conditioning approach is correct.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Moment generating functions seem to be a weak point for me. I guess for some reason treating the MGF as a random variable felt incorrect. But the more I think about it the more obvious valid it becomes!

Comment: You are welcome. The mgf is an expectation. And conditioning is a standard tool for calculating expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
\sum_k {n \choose k} \left( p M_Q(s) \right)^k (1-p)^{n-k}= \left(p M_Q(s)+1-p\right)^L
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, I was more worried about my reasoning and logic than the calculations! It was a problem I had read without giving it its due thought, and I'm currently not very familiar enough with moment generating functions to be sure I was approaching the problem in the right manner. Thanks for the help, though!